# Adding a document inside a document

Tags: graphics, pdf, minipage, tcolorbox, pdfpages

I'd like to include document inside a document. The basic idea behind that is to write a documentation about different type of classes one can use with latex.

Here is an example I would like to have:

[image]

For the moment I use following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.6\baselineskip-\height}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mp1}}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

An other solution is to use the `pdfpages` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\Usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includepdf[scale=0.2,pages=1,pagecommand={}]{ts.pdf}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

But the result is not convincing:

[image]

I would prefer to have a magical function that create a king of "minidocument" àla `minipage` such as:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{minidocument}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
      \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,]{article}
       ...
   \end{minidocument}
...
```

Is that possible or should I still compile multiple documents separately?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know `\input`  and  `\include`  and the packages `standalone`, `docmute`, `subfiles`, `subdocs` and `combine`?

Comment: @Andrew `listings` is more to display the code itself. Here my goal is to get the result of the listing.

Comment: @Fran all those commands are useful to include the source of a document inside the current one. My goal here is to provide the source and display its compiled form.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood...although I am still quite confused as to what you want as you are asking about writing documentation for the classes. Of course, with [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) you can also use escapes to run the actual code. I strongly doubt that it is possible to have an active `\documentclass` command, that differs from the `\documentclass` for the main document, inside an environment.

Comment: @Andrew that was my initial thought. maybe the `includepdf` is the best way.

Comment: It can be done in lualatex, by collecting the contents of the minidocument environment verbatim, and processing/compiling it.   Too much hassle and unclear to me what it's adding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Andrew said having a document class inside an other is not possible (IFAIK).

The `\includepdf` is not a good option because it mangles the output (see previous screenshot). Here is a working solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}%
  \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.6\baselineskip-\height}{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2,page=3]{ts.pdf}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2,page=4]{ts.pdf}}
  \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.6\baselineskip-\height}{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2,page=5]{ts.pdf}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2,page=6]{ts.pdf}}%
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

First you have to compile `ts.tex` into PDF and include one page with `\includegraphics` (note that you can only include one single page). OTOH this allows the included graphic to be scalable and selectable within the main document.
So if you need to add more page simply use `\includegraphics` several times.

Note that the `ts.pdf` only have 5 pages, including the 6th inexistant page is just for alignment here.

[image][image]

Comment: `tcolorbox` and it's option `/tcb/pdf comment=` can aslo be used (tcolobox manual page 300)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, here is a complete MWE about embedding a latex document within an other using `tcolorbox`. The `comment style` is very flexible. Note that the embedded document is a *real* document: you can select text and zoom without quality loss.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation,minted}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,raster}
\tcbset{
  tcbexample/.style = {%
    enhanced jigsaw,
    lower separated=false,
    leftlower=0pt,
    rightlower=0pt,
    boxrule=0.1pt,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    colback=white,
    listing engine=minted,
    minted options={breaklines,breakafter=()/+-\\,baselinestretch=0.5,fontsize=\footnotesize},
    comment style  = {raster columns=3, graphics pages={3,...,5}},
    comment and listing,
    pdf comment,
    compilable listing,
    run xelatex}
}


\begin{document}

Example of a embeded \LaTeX{} document:

\begin{tcblisting}{tcbexample}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-57]
\end{document}

\end{tcblisting}

Same example without the source code:

\begin{tcblisting}{tcbexample, comment only}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-57]
\end{document}

\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Note: you need `tcolorbox` > 3.91 to get the source code highlighted with `minted`.

[image]